# What am I doing wrong with positioning this inline element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a jQuery plugin [datepicker](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker) to show an inline calendar element inside of a column, but the calendar is being placed at the top left of the page, and I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

I've attached a picture of what I see on my screen. The red boxes are the two columns I'm working with, and I'm trying to get the date picker underneath the input field in the first column.

```js
var datepickerContainer = $('.datepicker-container');
$('.datepicker-input').datepicker({
  autoPick: true,
  inline: true,
  container: datepickerContainer,
});
```

```css
.datepicker-container {
  border: 1px dashed #eee;
  margin: 10px auto;
  min-height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.control-module {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.activity-feed {
  padding: 15px;
  list-style: none;
}

.feed-module {
  margin-top: 35px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.feed-positioning {
  padding: 0 0 0 0!important;
}


/* Date headers */

.date {
  width: 190px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  color: #8c96a3c0;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}


/* Messages */

.css-message {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.activity-feed>.css-message {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  border-left: 2px solid #e4e8ebf6;
}

.css-message:last-child {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.css-message::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -6px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #f37167;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="row d-flex myclass justify-content-around">

  <div class="p-2 control-module myclass">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="datepicker-input">
    </div>

    <div class="datepicker-container"></div>

    <nav class="nav flex-column"></nav>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex feed-module p-2">

    <ol class="list-of-days">
      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info date">
        <h4>Date
          <h4>
      </li>

      <ol class="activity-feed">
        <li class="feed-item css-message">message</li>
      </ol>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: page content]

Comment: actually, you can import the datepicker to the snippet, take it here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/datepicker

Comment: Oh awesome, I made a google search but I must have searched for it wrong. I updated the post

Comment: It seems to be at the right position in your snippet. Are you sure that the element is present in the DOM when you are running the JS code in your website?

Comment: @Morphyish When I run the snippet the element seems to be stickied in the top left corner of the page, similar to what i'm getting in my image. Also what exactly do you mean that the element is present in the DOM? It's definitely showing up on the page and the container is there

Comment: For reference, [the documentation page](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/) has exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Go to the page and toggle the "container" and "inline" buttons.

Comment: @Hunter you are right, because the snippet was so small I saw it wrong.

Comment: `.datepicker-container` by default on datepicker CSS file have a `left: 0; top: 0` properties, you can override it on your CSS, or you can wrap it in another div with position relative, the add this div wher you want and the calendar will be inside it

Comment: @CalvinNunes it also has a `position: fixed` property that can't be fixed by nesting the container.

Comment: ah, yeah, that's true

Comment: If the position is fixed you can actually delete position or comment it out.

Comment: @Juniar I ended up just resolving the naming conflict and renamed my class

Comment: @Hunter, fine. It`s possible to get rid of the plugin`s CSS if you also have other preferences you would like to customize such as color, font etc with your own CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the datepicker you are trying to use is bringing it's own css to the party and placing it on the container you chose:

```css
.datepicker-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    direction: ltr;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    width: 210px;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

Including some positioning properties.

The issue is that its css is loaded after your own, so it takes priority.

The good thing is that you have a few ways to fix it, you can either manage to load it before your own css, you can make a better selector for you own css to get priority back, or you can use the `!important` keyword to overwrite any properties you want.

Maybe look into the datepicker documentation as well to see if there's an option to disable that.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed this, rookie mistake!! Thanks so much.